# why i'm getting this error in rust? while running cargo in terminal

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

```
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "link.exe" "/NOLOGO" "/NXCOMPAT" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "F:\\rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\rust-62f257c00b684def.15picq4yh55pcpvu.rcgu.o" "F:\\rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\rust-62f257c00b684def.4a6f0gpq6tahn2qf.rcgu.o" "F:\\rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\rust-62f257c00b684def.4t2qllwq7vgsjzz0.rcgu.o" "F:\\rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\rust-62f257c00b684def.4zhitfql72c5zw8t.rcgu.o" "F:\\rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\rust-62f257c00b684def.63vl4u1eiyxg147.rcgu.o" "F:\\rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\rust-62f257c00b684def.aln6nw8r8p9cjoc.rcgu.o" "/OUT:F:\\rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\rust-62f257c00b684def.exe" "F:\\rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\rust-62f257c00b684def.5nv92ivk74xr163.rcgu.o" "/OPT:REF,NOICF" "/DEBUG" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\intrinsic.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\liballoc.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libcore.natvis" "/LIBPATH:F:\\rust\\target\\debug\\deps" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd-f3cd9033b21bfd69.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-7177cc63e2247a71.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libhashbrown-dc4f9fa6045181bb.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-b42f2443bfe541d3.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libbacktrace-727167d019576e4a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_demangle-b116c11df52ba1e2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libunwind-d4c5a28b76348d5c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcfg_if-79bcbf9ce75fa48d.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liblibc-c9478dd7b586b8cc.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liballoc-c80eff7d74f3988c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-fd0f5d5cd3b3863d.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcore-49f9f21b6d32d457.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-b32ee8ba444e5f7c.rlib" "advapi32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "userenv.lib" "msvcrt.lib"
  = note: /usr/bin/link: extra operand ‘/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\Grandpa\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib’
          Try '/usr/bin/link --help' for more information.


error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `rust`.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @AbhiSingh, please read the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good question and edit your with required details.

Comment: You seem to be running the wrong linker. Maybe [this issue on Github](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/3687) helps?

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't come with the tools you need out of the box.

One way to get the tools is to download Visual Studio and make sure you check the box for C/C++ Development.

Please do some searching around next time before you ask a new question. I'm pretty sure this is a common starting problem on Windows (having come across it myself)